# Using custom function getter as setter with setf

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I think it is apparent from this code what I'm *trying* to do, that is, change `'blue` to `'purple`:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter myassoc '((color red blue) (shape circle square)))
MYASSOC
CL-USER> myassoc
((COLOR RED BLUE) (SHAPE CIRCLE SQUARE))
CL-USER> (defun getsecondof (assoc) (second (rest (assoc assoc myassoc))))
GETSECONDOF
CL-USER> (getsecondof 'color)
BLUE
CL-USER> (setf (getsecondof 'color) 'purple)
; in: SETF (GETSECONDOF 'COLOR)
;     (FUNCALL #'(SETF GETSECONDOF) #:NEW954 'COLOR)
; ==>
;   (SB-C::%FUNCALL #'(SETF GETSECONDOF) #:NEW954 'COLOR)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: (SETF GETSECONDOF)
;
```

Now, if instead of using my own function `getsecondof` with `setf` I instead pass a built-in CL expression to extract the location I want to change, it works.

Is it possible to use custom getters as setters with `setf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a `setf` for it:

```
(defun (setf getsecondof) (assoc value)
  (setf (caddr (assoc assoc myassoc)) value)) ; (caddr x) == (second (rest x))

(setf (getsecondof 'color) 'purple) ; ==> PURPLE
(getsecondof 'color) ; ==> PURPLE
```

Comment: it would almost make more sense just to make a regular function for setting something, since the work appears to about the same, and then the function would perhaps be more clear or specific

Comment: @OpenLearner If you follow the approach that Sylwester has illustrated, then in documenting your function, you'd call `getsecondof` an _accessor_, in the same way that the HyperSpec [calls `car` an accessor](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm).  You could define the custom setting function, too (e.g., [`rplaca`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rplaca.htm), but that would just be called a function, not an accessor.  It's convenient to define accessors where appropriate, as it's one less function name to remember.

Comment: @OpenLearner: After you have defined the `setf`, you can regard the thing as a _place_.  There are more functions that take a place as argument, e. g. `rotatef`, `shiftf`, `push`, `pop`, `incf`, `decf`.

Answer (score 3):

You have do define a setf function.

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defset.htm#defsetf